# Get text of checked value from PDF using UiPath

Tags: uipath

Need to get text of checked and unchecked box value separately from PDF.

Using Start Process to read PDF file, by Find Element and Get Text property I'm getting require text. Now the problem is I want to get checked and unchecked values separately from PDF. I've already tried Get Attribute Activity but it only return Boolean Values.

[image]

Comment: Could you share this PDF?

Comment: No permission issues. The only thing which I can, I've already shared. 
In complete PDF Checkbox and Radio Button occurs only one time as shown above.

Comment: If you can't share this particular PDF, then find one you can. As of now, we have no clue what we might be dealing with (is it an embedded PDF form, just a JPEG image in a PDF, et cetera).

Comment: If i understood your query correctly, question has the answer, as you said 'get attribute' activity returning Boolean values, with this you can determine whether the check box is checked or not.  If i misinterpreted , give us more details on it.

Comment: Not sure what was asked. ProgSMI please add more info and a PDF file.